# Чтение файла вместе со строкой

Tags: c#

Вопрос простой: код считывает строки вместе с номером строки... типа так:

```
1(номер строки)_пробел_ текст строки    
string[] file1 = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Aim\Desktop\dig1.txt");
            foreach (var lines in file1)
            {
                    Console.WriteLine(a.ToString() + " " + lines);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }


foreach (var lines in file1) 
{ 
  for (int a = 0; a < lines.Length; a++) 
  { 
    Console.WriteLine(++a.ToString() + " " + lines); 
    Console.ReadKey(); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: вопрос.....вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Зачем нам вопрос? Вот ответ:  `(++a).ToString()`

Comment: @Igor а кто такой `a`  и откуда он взялся?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский
`foreach (var lines in file1)
            {
                for (int a = 0; a < lines.Length; a++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(++a.ToString() + " " + lines);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Не будем крохоборствовать. Откуда-то взялся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int a = 0;
foreach (var line in file1) 
{ 
  Console.WriteLine((++a).ToString() + " " + line); 
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: идеально.......

Comment: @tube галочка слева - щёлк :)